# pregunta de reduce

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código

Tengo el siguiente código pero no veo claro el porqué del `acc[student.name]` y del `, {}` del final, con números lo veo pero no entiendo porque `[]` para acceder al estudiante cuando pensé que sería con `.`:

```js
var students = [{
    name: "Tony Parker",
    firstProject: 80,
    secondProject: 75,
    finalExam: 90,
    age: 25,
    skills: ['C', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
  },
  {
    name: "Marc Barchini",
    firstProject: 84,
    secondProject: 65,
    finalExam: 65,
    age: 30,
    skills: ['Swift', 'JavaScript']
  },
  {
    name: "Claudia Lopez",
    firstProject: 45,
    secondProject: 95,
    finalExam: 99,
    age: 49,
    skills: ['Java', 'Pearl']
  },
  {
    name: "Alvaro Briattore",
    firstProject: 82,
    secondProject: 92,
    finalExam: 70,
    age: 24,
    skills: ['JavaScript', 'PHP']
  },
  {
    name: "Isabel Ortega",
    firstProject: 90,
    secondProject: 32,
    finalExam: 85,
    age: 21,
    skills: ['Lua', 'Python']
  },
  {
    name: "Francisco Martinez",
    firstProject: 90,
    secondProject: 55,
    finalExam: 78,
    age: 45,
    skills: ['C++', 'Python']
  },
  {
    name: "Jorge Carrillo",
    firstProject: 83,
    secondProject: 77,
    finalExam: 90,
    age: 32,
    skills: ['C#', 'C++', 'C']
  },
  {
    name: "Miguel López",
    firstProject: 80,
    secondProject: 75,
    finalExam: 75,
    age: 31,
    skills: ['Scala', 'Java']
  },
  {
    name: "Carolina Perez",
    firstProject: 85,
    secondProject: 72,
    finalExam: 67,
    age: 27,
    skills: ['Scala', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
  },
  {
    name: "Ruben Pardo",
    firstProject: 89,
    secondProject: 72,
    finalExam: 65,
    age: 28,
    skills: ['C#', 'JavaScript']
  }
]


var result = students.reduce(function(acc, student) {
  acc[student.name] = student.age;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso student representa cada uno de los objetos del array original.  El array acc es el acumulador o resultado de la funcion.  El resultado final usa como llave el nombre de cada objeto y como valor la edad.  Por eso para acceder al nombre de cada objeto se usa `student.name`.  Las {} del final son opcionales y es un valor inicial que se le puede pasar a reduce para la primera iteracion.

Comment: Gracias, pero querria saber porque es asi acc[student.name] en lugar de acc.student.name si estamos accediendo a un objeto.

Comment: Estamos accediendo a un array de objetos.  Cada elemento del array es un objeto representado por student.  Acc es otro array que va a ser el resultado final.  Queremos crear una nueva llave en el Array Acc que sea el nombre de cada estudiante.

Answer (score 0):

El segundo parámetro de `Array#reduce` representa el valor por defecto. Dicho esto, sabemos que será un objeto literal vacío.

```
var result = students.reduce(function(acc, student) {
  acc[student.name] = student.age;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Ahora bien, en cada iteración, se modifica dicho objeto para **agregarle una nueva clave** la cual es **el nombre del estudiante** y como valor, su edad.

---

Como extra, puedes reescribir esa función de la siguiente manera (ES6):

```js
const students = [{
    name: "Tony Parker",
    firstProject: 80,
    secondProject: 75,
    finalExam: 90,
    age: 25,
    skills: ['C', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
  },
  {
    name: "Marc Barchini",
    firstProject: 84,
    secondProject: 65,
    finalExam: 65,
    age: 30,
    skills: ['Swift', 'JavaScript']
  },
  {
    name: "Claudia Lopez",
    firstProject: 45,
    secondProject: 95,
    finalExam: 99,
    age: 49,
    skills: ['Java', 'Pearl']
  },
  {
    name: "Alvaro Briattore",
    firstProject: 82,
    secondProject: 92,
    finalExam: 70,
    age: 24,
    skills: ['JavaScript', 'PHP']
  },
  {
    name: "Isabel Ortega",
    firstProject: 90,
    secondProject: 32,
    finalExam: 85,
    age: 21,
    skills: ['Lua', 'Python']
  },
  {
    name: "Francisco Martinez",
    firstProject: 90,
    secondProject: 55,
    finalExam: 78,
    age: 45,
    skills: ['C++', 'Python']
  },
  {
    name: "Jorge Carrillo",
    firstProject: 83,
    secondProject: 77,
    finalExam: 90,
    age: 32,
    skills: ['C#', 'C++', 'C']
  },
  {
    name: "Miguel López",
    firstProject: 80,
    secondProject: 75,
    finalExam: 75,
    age: 31,
    skills: ['Scala', 'Java']
  },
  {
    name: "Carolina Perez",
    firstProject: 85,
    secondProject: 72,
    finalExam: 67,
    age: 27,
    skills: ['Scala', 'Java', 'JavaScript']
  },
  {
    name: "Ruben Pardo",
    firstProject: 89,
    secondProject: 72,
    finalExam: 65,
    age: 28,
    skills: ['C#', 'JavaScript']
  },
];

const result = students.reduce((acc, student) => ({
  ...acc,
  [student.name]: student.age,
}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Pero porque se accede con corchetes asi acc[student.name] no deberia ser con punto?

Comment: Te explico. Al hacer esto en un objeto: `object[variable]` estás creando una propiedad dentro de `object` con el contenido de `variable`. Yendo al ejemplo, si `acc.name` es `Jane Doe`, `=>` el objeto será `{ 'Jane Doe': <valor> }`. ¿Entiendes por qué no se usa punto? Porque **estamos creando propiedades** dinámicas.